# Online account login within app

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking-2

I am struggling to understand how you would create an app which would allow the user to log into their online account at a website. My example would be logging into here: https://account.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/

Now I've read a lot about AFNetworking, HTTP POST requests etc, but I am very confused about how this all relates (if at all) to my example website login above.

Any advice on the way to go about this login would be great as I am completely lost.

Comment: Actually you don't login 'through' site but using REST (SOAP) services using e.g. JSON. You should find/get REST specification (if any exists) and there you will get all required info about server-client communication. Once you get it you can send via POST (params in NSDictionary) or GET (params goes in query) request to server. Hope it clarify a little.

Answer (score 0):

Use following way :

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];  //may be change as per your requirement

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yourDoamin.com/test/xyz.aspx"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connected");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    // here check response data in your case login password true or false
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   // handle connection error
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
}
```